I get an error with when loading 2sxc 17.9 edit form?
Just installed 2sxc 17.9 on an DNN 9.11 and at first it seemed to work.
However when I try to edit, the popup won't open. When I look with F12, I get:
"
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
"
On ../desktopmodules/tosic_sexycontent/dist/ng-edit/default-node_modules_angular_material_fesm2022_card_mjs.bc98c2543b582cb0.js
Perhaps it is something with the 2 dots in the filename?
I think I should modify something in the mime types or something.
Anyone knows what to do?

This is a very unusual issue, and almost certainly caused by your system, since others are using 17.09 successfully. I suggest you add more context, maybe screenshot of F12 network tab or something. Also check what you have in terms of additional security settings, eg. CSP since it does say that it's doing "strict mime checking". and also check what mime-types the server gives for other js files.

Looks like it is something on the server indeed. When I tested on a local copy everything works. I'll ask the provider for more info, thanks...
